# Como usar uma função de variável várias vezes sem precisar criar outra variável? Como por exemplo sortear um número

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
n = random.randint(1, 6)
print('O valor sorteado foi {}'.format(n))
if nd !=n:
    print('Não foi dessa vez')
if nd ==n:
    print('Parabéns! Você está com sorte')
start1 = str(input('Deseja continuar? '))
if start1 =='Sim':
    nd1 = int(input('Qual valor você deseja? De 1 até 6? '))
else: exit()
n1 = random.randint(1, 6)
print('O valor sorteado foi {}'.format(n1))
if nd1 ==n1:
    print('Parabéns! Você está com sorte')
else: print('Não foi dessa vez!')

> Citação
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você está procurando é um laço de repetição como o while, ou seja um comando que repete um conjunto de instruções enquanto as condições para que ela continuem sejam verdadeiras, exemplo a partir do seu código:

```
import random
start1 = 'Sim'
while (start1 == 'Sim'):
  nd = int(input('Qual valor você deseja? De 1 até 6? '))
  n = random.randint(1, 6)
  print('O valor sorteado foi {}'.format(n))
  if nd !=n:
    print('Não foi dessa vez')
  else:
    print('Parabéns! Você está com sorte')
  
  start1 = str(input('Deseja continuar? '))    #Ao chegar aqui ele irá voltar para o while e caso o start1 permaneça como 'Sim' então ele executará novamente
exit()
```

Comment: Lucas, eu posso aplicar essa propriedade while a variável n também?

Comment: não entendi o motivo de fazer isso separadamente, perceba que o while irá rodar tudo dentro do seu escopo

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi, você está tentando criar um joguinho de adivinhação. Onde o computador irá sortear um valor entre **1** e **6** e o usuário tentará descobrir o valor sorteado pelo computador.

Pois bem, para montarmos o código, devemos:

1. Importar a biblioteca **random**, bem como o método **randint**;
2. Sortear um valor entre **1** e **6**, armazenando-o em uma variável;
3. Implementar um laço de repetição para capturar o valor digitado pelo usuário;
4. Verificar se o valor do usuário corresponde ao valor sorteado;
5. Exibir uma mensagem de aprovação ou desaprovação.

Com esta lógica e utilizando **[Assignment Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)**, podemos montar o seguinte código:

```
from random import randint

cont = 1
s = randint(1, 6)
while (n := int(input('Digite um valor entre "1" e "6": '))) != s:
    print('Não foi desta vez. Tente novamente.')
    cont += 1

print(f'Parabéns! Você acertou o valor "{s}" na {cont}º tentativa!')
```

Observe que quando executamos o referido código, é realizado o sorteio. Em seguida, nos é solicitado para digitarmos um valor. Posteriormente o código verifica se o valor digitado corresponde ao valor sorteado. Caso positivo, recebermos uma mensagem positiva. Caso negativo, receberemos uma mensagem de desaprovação e, em seguida, seremos novamente solicitado um valor.